# Trying to find all records that are in one table and not both tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do I subtract the results of QUERY 2 from QUERY 1? Query 1 is my main query, cust_id is the connection between the two tables. So in essence query 2 is an additional filter criteria for query 1.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a `not in` condition, are you familiar with it?

Comment: I also tried NOT IN that too didn't seem to work correctly

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: VWC.CUST_ID NOT IN (SELECT CUST_ID FROM FND_ORD WHERE CUST_ID IS NOT NULL) ----- its as if the second query is not working at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking at returning records that appear in table 1 but not in table2, given an identifier id, you could look at using NOT EXISTS

select t1.id from table t1 where not exists (select * from table t2 where t1.id = t2.id)

This will return all records from table t1 where t1.id does not exist in t2. Add any additional qualifications and/or joins as required

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you are trying to filter out customerIDs that are getting returned from query2.

If this is the case then  before the

```
ORDER BY
```

you can add to the query

```
AND CUST_ID NOT IN (--here you drop in query 2--)
```

Comment: With the usual caveat if `cust_id` may be `null` in the subquery.

Comment: no errors just the records that I do not want to be there are still there

Comment: try adding to your inner query "where  CUST_ID is not null"

Comment: VWC.CUST_ID NOT IN (SELECT CUST_ID FROM FND_ORD WHERE CUST_ID IS NOT NULL)                                                                              
                  -----                                                             
  its as if the second query is not working at all

Comment: @Adam - So, what you are saying is that some rows from Query 1 should be rejected by the NOT IN clause, but the NOT IN clause doesn't reject anything. Are you sure there are CUST_ID's in Query 1, which exist in FND_ORD? If so, then something else is wrong with your code; NOT IN is the correct approach to what you asked in your post. And the issue with NULL, in any case, would result in NO rows being output by the total query (not handling NULL in the subquery would cause ALL the rows to be REJECTED, not RETAINED).